# Prepare hash for "grouped_options_for_select"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to prepare a hash for a select on my view.

For the moment I have this ugly thing.

```
@platforms = {}
Platform.all.each do |platform| 
  @platforms[platform.name] = platform.game_updates
                                      .includes(:game)
                                      .where(game: {store_id: current_store.id})
                                      .map {|game_update| [game_update.name, game_update.game.id] }
end
```

I want to have something like this :

```
@platforms = {
  'Plateform America' => [['Fallout4',76896], ['Just',56774]],
  'Plateform Ed' => [[Fallout3',77445],['Fallout2',75674],['Mario',45677]]
}
```

I have two problems. `Game` can have many `GameUpdates`. And for the moment the list show all the game_updates. It's like having `Fallout4.1`, `Fallout4.2`, `Fallout4.3` and I only want the last `Games_update` of `Game`.

Other problem is to refactor the first code. I've try to play with `group_by` without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to keep a foreign key last_game_update in your game table.  In this way a game can have many updates but only one last update

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_updates
  belongs_to :last_game_update, class_name: GameUpdate
end
```

Then your query becomes much more simplified at the small price of ensuring the game table keeps an up to date reference to the game updates table